# hi, im trying to create a pivot table that has documents received in a particular week and documents replied in that particular week. data source

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

im trying to create a pivot table that has documents received in a particular week and documents replied in that particular week. In data source, documents replied column has some empty cells since not all of them are replied. i think my pivot table goes wrong because of these empty cells. what should i do so that the pivot table counts only the replied documents in the particular week?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwdDE.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5hY1.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: empty cells should not be counted in a pivot table, maybe you are using sum instead of count in whatever you are putting in the values area...